# Docker build gives error when run with codepipeline aws

Tags: docker, aws-codepipeline, cicd, docker-build

I'm getting following error when I run Dockerfile with AWS CodePipeline

```
Step 2/4 : COPY src /app
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src: file does not exist
```

This is the command used in buildspec.yml

`docker build --tag $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG -f app/Dockerfile` .

folder structure is:

```
Microservice1/
             |-app/
               |- src/
               |- Dockerfile
             |-buildspec.yml
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are executing command at $Microservice1 directory.

   Dot (.) at the end of command tells to use build context as current directory.

   Docker build context can see only app/src , only src is not visible.
2. Alternatively, execute command from $Microservice1/app directory. You may have to change Dockerfile a bit.